# Improve timing of URLExecute command?

Tags: parallelization, web-access, timing, internet

I am using a ionosphere model that runs online, IRI2016. 
The URL gives me a table with usefull parameters like electron density in upper atmosphere.

The `URLExecute` part of my code is

```
URLExecute["https://omniweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/vitmo/vitmo_model.cgi", 
  {"model"->"iri_2016","year"->2015,"month"->11,"day"->22,"time_flag"->0,"hour"->1,"geo_flag"-> 0,"latitude"->10,"longitude"->10,"height"->120,"profile"-> 1,"start"->80,"stop"->1000,"step"->1,"vars"-> 17}, Method -> "GET"]
```

The problem is that I need to run several the code times to create a map (180 latitude x 360 longitude) and parallelize is not enough since it takes 1.5s for each call.

How can I do it faster?

Comment: How do you know that the bottleneck is in *Mathematica*, and not in the response time from the server combined with the speed of your connection?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate: [77442](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77442/731). You don't have to use `URLExecute` for this, and probably shouldn't.