# Geolocate multiple IP addresses

Tags: performance-tuning, geography, networking

I would like to geolocate a few hundred IP addresses (as part of analysing server logs).  What is the best way to do this using Mathematica?

Does Mathematica have any builtin functionality for this?

Is the best approach to try to query an online service instead? Is there one which is easy to use from Mathematica and would be able to handle up to 1000 addresses?

Should I try to find a database and use it offline from Mathematica?

I am not necessarily looking for working code. A general high-level guide on the best approach will be sufficient.

---

**Update:** For this application, performance is important. Here's a dataset to use as benchmark:

```
websites = 
  WolframAlpha[
   "top websites", {{"OrdinalRankings", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
   PodStates -> {"OrdinalRankings__More", "OrdinalRankings__More", 
     "OrdinalRankings__More", "OrdinalRankings__More", 
     "OrdinalRankings__More"}];

Length[websites]
(* 160 *)

iplist = First /@ 
   Flatten@DeleteMissing[HostLookup /@ websites[[All, 2]]];

Length[iplist]
(* 355 *)
```

Comment: You can use `URLExecute["freegeoip.net/json/someIP"]`. They allow 15000 api calls per hour, although using the above takes approx 0.7s on my computer/connection per call. Maybe you can use `URLSaveAsynchronous` as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77442/is-there-a-better-way-to-download-images-in-parallel)

Comment: You can also use `FindGeoLocation`. It's very slow though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Somehow I did not notice this function.  It's worth an answer, even if it is slow.

Comment: I'll put in a quick one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Batch mode API call, for best performance

From the documentation at http://ip-api.com/docs/api:batch
"Batch JSON", a batch processing with the ability to query multiple IP addresses in one HTTP request, significantly faster than submitting individual queries.
A batch request requires a POST request to http://ip-api.com/batch with a Body string in JSON array format, containing up to 100 objects. Therefore, here the `ipLongList` arguments is [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) into as many `ipShortList` as necessary.

Free for non-commercial use only!

```
BatchIP2Location[ipLongList : List[_String ..]] := 
 AssociationThread[ipLongList,
  Flatten@Table[
    Query[Values, GeoPosition][
     ImportString[
      URLRead[
       HTTPRequest[
        "http://ip-api.com/batch",
        <|
         Method -> "POST",
         "Query" -> {"fields" -> "lat,lon"},
         "Body" -> 
          ExportString[
           Map[{"query" -> #} &, ipShortList], 
           "JSON"]
         |>]
       , "Body"], {"RawJSON"}]
     ],
    {ipShortList, Partition[ipLongList, UpTo[99]]}
    ]]
```

### Performance

```
Length@iplist
(* 358 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming@BatchIP2Location@iplist
(* 0.525389 *)
```

Answer (score 18):

It seems to be possible to get this data directly in Mathematica using entities.  Here's an example:

Let's get a list of IP addresses to work with:

```
ips = 
 First@*First@*HostLookup /@ {"wolfram.com", "stackexchange.com", 
   "google.com", "baidu.com", "www.elysee.fr", "global.jaxa.jp", 
   "qwant.com", "eso.org"}
(* {"206.123.112.238", "151.101.1.69", "216.58.198.206", \
"220.181.57.217", "207.123.33.126", "202.32.9.55", "194.187.168.99", \
"134.171.75.1"} *)
```

Transform them into entities:

```
entityList = Entity["IPAddress", #] & /@ ips;
```

The coordinates are available as a property:

```
EntityProperties@First[entityList]
(* {EntityProperty["IPAddress", "Address"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "Country"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "FullIPv6Address"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "HostCoordinates"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "HostLocation"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "HostOrganization"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "HostSegment"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "IPv4Address"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "IPv6Address"], 
 EntityProperty["IPAddress", "Name"]} *)
```

Let's get them all at once:

```
coords = 
   EntityValue[entityList, "HostCoordinates"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.976854, Null} *)
```

And plot them:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker@GeoPosition[coords], GeoRange -> "World"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Optionally use `DeleteMissing[coords]` to remove failed lookups.

---

Timing using the benchmark dataset:

```
coord = 
   EntityValue[Entity["IPAddress", #] & /@ iplist, "HostCoordinates"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.68313, Null} *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work properly  with {"wolfram.com","stackexchange.com","google.com","lute.lviv.ua","global.jaxa.jp","qwant.com","eso.org"} though 7 addresses {"140.177.205.134", "151.101.193.69", "172.217.20.206", \
"194.44.248.4", "202.32.9.55", "194.187.168.99", "134.171.75.1"} are produced.

Comment: @user64494 Seems to work for me ...

Comment: But not properly. There are six points instead of seven points in  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m3wbg4pzmlpo1j/geo.pdf?dl=0 .

Comment: @user64494 I can confirm that it works properly for me, too. It seems that for you, the addresses get resolved to different IPs, two of which have coordinates very close together. You can check this by looking at `coords` or by making the map bigger (the leftmost marker is actually two)

Comment: You are completely right. Your original example demonstrates difficulties a Mathematica user may face.

Comment: When running `EntityProperties["IPAddress"]` in MMA 11.1.1.0 I get nothing but `EntityProperties["IPAddress"]` returned back. On Windows 10. Strange!

Comment: @PlatoManiac I can reproduce that. I think it's a bug in 11.1.1.  I edited the post, can you try with this new syntax?

Comment: @Szabolcs With `EntityProperties@First[entityList]` I get `EntityProperties[Entity["IPAddress", "206.123.112.238"]]` back I think it is a bug as you said.

Answer (score 11):

Do not apply this method to long lists, where Batch mode would be more efficient and less abusive to the API provider. See [this other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155112/10397).

### 3 API Integrated solution (One API call per IP)

```
ClearAll[IP2Location];
Options[IP2Location] = {Method -> Automatic};
SetAttributes[IP2Location, Listable]
IP2Location[ip_String | IPAddress[ip_String], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Block[{url, response, methodlist, method, latlon},
  methodlist = {"nekudo", "freegeoip", "ip-api"};
  method = If[
    OptionValue[Method] === Automatic || FreeQ[methodlist, OptionValue[Method]],
    RandomChoice[methodlist],
    OptionValue[Method]
    ];
  url = URLBuild@Switch[method,
     "nekudo", <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "geoip.nekudo.com", "Path" -> {"api", ip}|>,
     "freegeoip", <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "freegeoip.net", "Path" -> {"json", ip}|>,
     "ip-api", <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "ip-api.com", "Path" -> {"json", ip}|>
     ];
  response = Import[url, "RawJSON"];
  latlon = ToExpression@Values[
     Switch[method,
       "nekudo", Query["location", {"latitude", "longitude"}],
       "freegeoip", Query[{"latitude", "longitude"}],
       "ip-api", Query[{"lat", "lon"}]
       ][response]
     ];
  (*Echo[response,method];*)
  GeoLocation[latlon]
  ]
```

### Performance

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@IP2Location[iplist]
(*37.6867*)
```

Failed in 7 sites.

Comment: Might be a good idea to just have one routine with a `Method` option taking whatever geolocation services are implemented (e.g. `IPToLocation[ip, Method -> "FreeGeoIP"]`).

Comment: I find it amusing that `Automatic` corresponds to a random choice... :D

Comment: @J.M. **Beware that not all services return the same coordinates!**
 `IP2Location["206.123.112.238", Method -> #] & /@ {"nekudo", 
  "freegeoip", "ip-api"}` `(*{GeoLocation[{28.5383, -81.3792}], GeoLocation[{28.5383, -81.3792}], 
 GeoLocation[{38.6143, -90.4444}]}*)`

Comment: Correct, and that's exactly why it's useful to be able to check multiple sources whenever possible, since this is known to be a fuzzy problem. Personally, I'm amused that checking my IP shows that I am located three or four towns away from my actual location. ;)

Comment: Could you please try one with the big IP list I added in the edit?  Or a ubset if it's too big. I am having trouble getting this working for reasons not related to your code so I couldn't try yet.

Comment: You could update the argument pattern to be `ip_String | IPAddress[ip_String]`.  That's a weird pattern, and I am surprised that it works at all (but it does).

Comment: Like API method!

Comment: Since you brought up the inconsistency of geolocation services, here is another suggestion: why not have a setting `Method -> All` that returns an `Association[]` where a service and its returned location are paired, for all available services?

Comment: If you are going to put in this much work, you should wrap it up into a package and put it on GitHub.

Comment: @rhermans OP is around so you don't need mod to delete obsolete comments.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the most concise way is through [`FindGeoLocation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeoLocation.html).

It's easy to use, but crushingly slow:

```
FindGeoLocation /@ HostLookup["www.wolfram.com"] // RepeatedTiming

{0.43, {GeoPosition[{40.1125, -88.2426}], 
  GeoPosition[{28.5383, -81.3792}]}}
```