# URLDownloadSubmit is not asynchronous?

Tags: import, web-access, webservices, url

I'm trying to download a few thousand images (using an authenticated get request). This [explanation of parallel downloading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77442/is-there-a-better-way-to-download-images-in-parallel) was a great answer to the problem of handling massive parallel asynchronous downloads. But that solution no longer works for me, and now in v11.2 there are completely new URL-related functions...

The function `URLDownloadSubmit` is supposed to replace `URLFetchAsynchronous`, but I'm finding that it's not asynchronous and very slow. Here's what my code looks like now using `URLDownloadSubmit`, and it's clearly downloading things sequentially:

[image]

Has anyone come across this in v11.2 and know how to address it?

**Additional Details:**

- Even if I `DistributeDefinitions` and then `ParallelMap` my submitting function, nothing happens:

  [image: enter image description here)]

Comment: This is gonna be some throttle at the asynchronous task level. If you look at the `DownValues` I think `URLFetchAsynchronous` has an implementation at the CURL level, hence the difference. It looks buggy to me. Ask support.

Comment: @b3m2a1 seems like they keep making new versions of url related functions, but they keep getting worse!

Comment: Just from the `DownValues` it looks like they're trying to move away from using an external library for all of this stuff, which makes sense, but the transition is gonna be a bit bumpy. Until `PacletFind["CURLLink"]` is empty (which probably won't be until V15 or something), the old stuff will work.